# Parse Json file in php

Tags: php, json

i want to parse json file in php function, to find if status is equal to "created" or not and that's waht id :

```
function getRsponseFromJSON ($json){
$status = "status";
$chaine = json_decode($json);
    foreach($chaine->status as $stat) {
        if ($stat == "created") {
            return $resp = "ok";
        } else {
            return $resp = "notok";
    }
}
}
```

and this is my json file :

```
{
"data": {
    "aliases": [],
    "app_url": "http://myapp-MyDomain.rhcloud.com/",
    "build_job_url": null,
    "building_app": null,
    "building_with": null,
    "creation_time": "2013-04-22T03:12:13Z",
    "domain_id": "MyDomain",
    "embedded": {
        "haproxy-1.4": {}
    },
"status": "created",
"type": "application",
}
```

and that what i get in error :

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Comment: `$chaine->status` is not an array

Comment: Why would status be traversable (usable in a foreach) ? It's a string...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$chaine->status` is a string, so I guess you just have to drop this useless foreach, like this :

```
<?php
function getRsponseFromJSON ($json){
    $chaine = json_decode($json);

    return ($chaine->status == "created") ? "ok": "notok";
}
```